# Display results of query in a table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have table, `'mags_sold'` in the database with 3 columns:

`date`, `name of magazine`, `number sold`.

Every day I run a cronjob that inserts 3 new lines with that days date the name of the magazine and how many were sold that day. (I have 3 magazines).

I would like to display the data in a table.

I've set it up with 4 columns. `Date` and `mag1`, `mag2`, `mag3`.

I have a query `SELECT * FROM 'mags_sold'` but I don't know how to loop through the results to display them so the date only displays once, and the number sold shows under each heading.

```
<?php
$values = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'mags_sold'"));
?>
<table id="email_subscription">
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>mag1</th>   
<th>mag2</th>
<th>mag3</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($values as $email_signup){
$id = $email_signup->id;
$list_name = array($email_signup->list_name);
$date = $email_signup->date;
echo       '<tr><td>' . $date . '</td>';
$sold_count = array($email_signup->sold_count);
       echo '<td>' . $sold_count[0] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $sold_count[1] . '</td>';  
       echo '<td>' . $sold_count[2] . '</td>';  
 echo    '</tr>';
 }
 ?>   
</table>
```

But this code  shows a separate line for each date and sold count.

var_dump using code:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[637]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-05' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132467' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'F' => string '15330' (length=5)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[549]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-04' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132467' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'F' => string '15330' (length=5)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[547]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-03' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132467' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'F' => string '15330' (length=5)
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[548]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-05' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132462' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '98577' (length=5)
      public 'F' => string '15343' (length=5)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[467]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-04' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132462' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '98577' (length=5)
      public 'F' => string '15343' (length=5)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[468]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-03' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132462' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '98577' (length=5)
      public 'F' => string '15343' (length=5)
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[547]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-05' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132468' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'F' => string '15349' (length=5)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[549]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-04' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132468' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'F' => string '15349' (length=5)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[637]
      public 'date' => string '2015-05-03' (length=10)
      public 'B' => string '132468' (length=6)
      public 'D' => string '6' (length=1)
      public 'F' => string '15349' (length=5)
```

Comment: I don't understand. 'mags_sold' is a string

Comment: Can you do a print_r of `$email_signup` just below the foreach statement and post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an MYSQL query which returns for each unique date the following line :

```
date         magazine_1      magazine_2      magazine_3
2015-04-05   *number_sold*  *number_sold*    *number_sold*
```

So where *number_sold* is equal to the COUNT of number sold where `name_of_magazine` is equal to magazine_1, 2 3 etc.

At the moment your query is selecting all from the `mags_sold` table and then the foreach is doing exactly what it should in that it's returning each line seperately.

See the below MYSQL fiddle : -

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85ad0)

**SOLUTION**

OK so you could try this : -

```
<?php
$values = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM mags_sold"));
?>
<table id="email_subscription">
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>mag1</th>   
<th>mag2</th>
<th>mag3</th>
</tr>
<?php

    foreach($values as $email_signup){

        $date = $email_signup->date;

        $sold_values = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT DISTINCT `date`,
        (select number_sold from mags_sold where name_of_magazine = 'weekly news' AND date = $date) as 'weekly_news',
        (select number_sold from mags_sold where name_of_magazine = 'monthly news' AND date = $date) as 'monthly_news',
        (select number_sold from mags_sold where name_of_magazine = 'todays news' AND date = $date) as 'todays_news'
        from mags_sold  
        WHERE date = $date "));

        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $sold_values->weekly_news. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $sold_values->monthly_news . '</td>';  
            echo '<td>' . $sold_values->todays_news . '</td>';  
        echo '</tr>';

    }
 ?>   
</table>
```

Replace the dummy magazine names, i.e. `weekly_news, monthly_news` with the name of your magazines and that should work.

Comment: Thank you. It is giving me the correct array, but 3 of the same arrays. Also . $sold_values->todays_news . '</td>'; is giving me a whitescreen. How do I echo the results .

Comment: @LTech - You'll need to replace `weekly_news, monthly_news, todays news` with the names of your own magazines. This was done just for illustration purposes. Please provide me with a `var_dump` of the `$sold_values` array during the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I used your code exactly (obviously making the changes to correspond to my tables). The var_dump is in the question above. Nothing is showing when I do       echo '<td>' . $counts->B . '</td>'; I think the foreach loop is causing to show the data 3 times but if I put the query outside the loop       echo '<td>' . $counts->Breaking_News_Videos . '</td>';  shows the same value 3 times

Comment: I'm not sure your example on sql fiddle is working as all the values say 12?

Comment: @LTech - See my updated answer, I'm sorry I made a mistake. Let me know if that solves the problem.

Comment: @LTech - Welcome! It's not the best way of doing the query but if it gives you the correct result.

Comment: I have a very busy site with 1,000s of users a second. If you could direct me to a better way of doing the query that would be more efficient I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @LTech - I'll have a think and get back to you with a better solution at some point during the week.